# Issue loading rxjs bundle with SystemJs

Tags: typescript, systemjs, rxjs5

**Versions**

`npm: 3.10.9`
`systemjs: 0.19.41`
`typescript: 1.8.10`
`rxjs: 5.0.3`

**Background**

I have a project (that's written in typescript) that i'm trying to add `rxjs` to, but have come across an issue when loading the bundled file through `systemjs`.

**SystemJs config**

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    paths: {
        'src:*': '/src/*',
        'npm:*': '/node_modules/*'
    },
    map: {
        'lib': 'src:lib',
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
        'typescript': 'npm:typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'systemjs': 'npm:systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    packages: {
        lib: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

**Problem**

Using the above config, i get the following error.

```
Error: (SystemJS) undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '__extends(UnsubscriptionError, _super)')
```

Which is caused by the fact that systemjs incorrectly defaults to `amd` format and the `exporter` function on line 245 of `Rx.js` never gets executed.

From the systemjs docs:

> **Module format detection**
>
> When the module format is not set, automatic regular-expression-based    detection is used. This module format detection is never completely accurate, but caters well for the majority use cases.

**Attempted solution**

I presumed that explicitly setting the `rxjs` package format to `global` in the config would fix this issue.

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    paths: {
        'src:*': '/src/*',
        'npm:*': '/node_modules/*'
    },
    map: {
        'lib': 'src:lib',
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
        'typescript': 'npm:typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'systemjs': 'npm:systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    packages: {
        lib: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            format: 'global'
        }
    }
});
```

**Problem 2**

Although this fixed the first issue, it created a second. As everywhere that i attempt to use the `rxjs` imports now throws an error, as they're `undefined`.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'

export class SomeClass {

    ...
    
    private _isObservable(arg: any): boolean {
        return arg instanceof Observable;
    }
}
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object at SomeClass._isObservable`

Debugging the transpiled code in the console reveals that although `window.Rx` gets correctly set to the `Rx` object, the `rxjs_1_1` object that gets set on `SomeClass`, is not the global `Rx` object, but instead another object with the `Rx` global set as a property 'Rx' on it.

So `rxjs_1.Rx.Observable` works, but not of rxjs_1.Observable`.

```
(function(System, SystemJS) {System.register(['rxjs'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
"use strict";
var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
var rxjs_1;
var SomeClass;
return {
    setters:[
        function (rxjs_1_1) {
            rxjs_1 = rxjs_1_1;
        }],
    execute: function() {
        SomeClass = (function () {
            function SomeClass() {
            }
            ...
            SomeClass.prototype._isObservable = function (arg) {
                return arg instanceof rxjs_1.Observable;
            };
            return SomeClass;
        }());
        exports_1("SomeClass", SomeClass);
    }
}
```

});

**Question**

Any idea how i get it to pass in `Rx` object instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `'Rx'` as the `meta.rxjs.exports` value in `system.config`, it allows you to select the `Rx` object to be imported, instead of its parent. You can use dot notation to select an even deeper object if necessary.

Not that you would want to, but just as an example, `exports: 'Rx.Observable'` would set the property `rxjs_1_1` to `Observable` in my original questions transpiled code.

So the full `system.config` would be:

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    paths: {
        'src:*': '/src/*',
        'npm:*': '/node_modules/*'
    },
    map: {
        'lib': 'src:lib',
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
        'typescript': 'npm:typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'systemjs': 'npm:systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    packages: {
        lib: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },
    meta: {
        rxjs: {
            format: 'global',
            exports: 'Rx'
        }
    }
});
```